# serial and parallel(using mpi) code for histogram of an image

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

can anyone help me in writing  code for histogram generation of an image in c language ? I know basic logic but not able to write code.I want a parallel program for the same.

```
 for(i=0; i<256;i++)
 histogram[i]=0;   
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
   for(j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
    color=image[i][j];
    histogram[color]++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would use threads (vs. processes) to parallelize this task (pthreads on Unix). In doing so, all of the threads can share the same pool of data (rather than having to copy voluminous amounts of image data across process boundaries).

One approach would be to query a system call to determine how many CPU threads (n) the system has. Then, allocate (n) separate histogram arrays. Partition the image into (n) horizontal slices. Then, create (n) threads and pass a different number (1..n) to each. Each thread will process the histogram data for a different slice and put the results in a different histogram array.

The main thread waits for the (n) worker threads to complete and then adds the (n) histogram arrays together into a final histogram array.

That's one way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenMP](http://openmp.org/mp-documents/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf) makes this nice and simple:

```
#pragma omp for
 for(i=0; i<256;i++)
 histogram[i]=0;   
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
   for(j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
    color=image[i][j];
    histogram[color]++;
    }
```

Comment: thnx for your help. i have to implement it using mpi on windows os.